# Is it possible to have a Community with Lightning look and feel?

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, partner-communities

In community cloud is there a way to have a community based on The 'Salesforce Tabs and visual force' But instead of classic salesforce Tabs we have Lightning Tabs?